# How to overlay a barplot on top of other plot with a different geom, by mapping the barplot positions to the original plot's scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to overlay a barplot on top of an existing plot, *by mapping* the positions of the new barplot to the values of the original plot.

### Example

Using the `mpg` dataset from the `{ggplot2}` package, I want to assess the relationship between the variables `cty` and `manufacturer`. To keep this simple, I'll focus on 3 manufacturers only.

#### Step 1 -- data for analysis

I'm going to add another column that categorizes the `cty` values into 3 categories `"low"`, `"medium"`, `"high"`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_manuf <- c("audi", "ford", "dodge")

my_df <-
  mpg %>%
  filter(manufacturer %in% my_manuf) %>%
  select(manufacturer, cty) %>%
  mutate(cty_range = case_when(between(cty, 9, 13) ~ "low",
                               between(cty, 13, 16) ~ "medium",
                               between(cty, 16, 21) ~ "high"))

my_df
#> # A tibble: 80 x 3
#>    manufacturer   cty cty_range
#>    <chr>        <int> <chr>    
#>  1 audi            18 high     
#>  2 audi            21 high     
#>  3 audi            20 high     
#>  4 audi            21 high     
#>  5 audi            16 medium   
#>  6 audi            18 high     
#>  7 audi            18 high     
#>  8 audi            18 high     
#>  9 audi            16 medium   
#> 10 audi            20 high     
#> # ... with 70 more rows
```

#### Step 2 -- fit a (very) simple model

2.1) Going to fit the model `lm(cty ~ manufacturer)`

```r
library(emmeans)
library(ggeffects)

model_results <- 
  my_df %>%
  lm(cty ~ manufacturer, data = .) %>%
  ggeffects::ggemmeans(terms = "manufacturer") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(manufacturer = x)

model_results
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   manufacturer predicted std.error conf.low conf.high group
#>   <fct>            <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>
#> 1 audi              17.6     0.521     16.6      18.6 1    
#> 2 dodge             13.1     0.364     12.4      13.9 1    
#> 3 ford              14       0.442     13.1      14.9 1
```

2.2) Going to merge `model_results` with `my_df` to be able to add raw data points to the plot.

```r
data_for_plot <- left_join(my_df, model_results)
```

#### Step 3 -- visualize

```r
p <-
  data_for_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = manufacturer, y = predicted)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = round(predicted, 2))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0.2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = manufacturer, y = predicted, color = cty_range)) +
  expand_limits(y = c(12, 21)) +
  theme_minimal()

p
```

[image]

---

#### Desired output

I want to add a barplot aligned to each `manufacturer`, to account for the proportion of the `cty_range` variable in each of its categories ("low"/"medium"/"high").
In my mind I imagine it as something like the following (not drawn to scale but values are real):

[image: image_with_demo]

---

I know there are tools from packages such as `patchwork` and `cowplot`. However, here I want to map the barplots to the x-axis scale, such that the barplot relevant to `audi` will be positioned respectively, etc.

Second, I wish there's an easy way to achieve this by simply *adding* another "barplot prop" `geom` to the structure that constructs `p`. This is because `p` already originates from `data_for_plot`, which has all the info we need to compute the proportions for the barplots (i.e., via `dplyr::count()` or alike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `patchwork::inset_element`you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

my_df_bar <- my_df %>% 
  count(manufacturer, cty_range) %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n),
         cty_range = factor(cty_range, levels = c("low", "medium", "high")))

p_bar <- ggplot(my_df_bar, aes(manufacturer, pct, fill = cty_range)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(width = .9)) +
  geom_text(aes(y = pct - .01, label =scales::percent(pct)), 
            position = position_dodge2(width = .9),
            size = 8 / .pt, vjust = 1) +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = "none")

library(patchwork)  

p + inset_element(p_bar, 0, .8, 1, 1)
```

[image]

**EDIT** Personally I would go for `patchwork`. (; But as an alternative approach you could achieve your result like so.

Most tricky part is to put the bars on top of the error bars and jitters which requires some transformation of the data similar to the ones necessary in case of a second-axis. Not sure whether it is easier to generalize this approach.

```r
trans <- 21
scale <- 5

breaks_fun <- function(x) {
  scales::breaks_extended()(x + trans) - trans
}

p <-
  data_for_plot %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = manufacturer, y = predicted - trans)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = round(predicted, 2))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low - trans, 
                    ymax = conf.high - trans), width = 0.2) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = manufacturer, y = predicted - trans, color = cty_range)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks_fun, labels = ~ .x + trans) +
  theme_minimal()

pct <- function(count, group) {
  count / tapply(count, group, sum)[group]
}

p +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = cty_range,
               y = scale * after_stat(pct(count, x))),
            stat = "count", position = position_dodge2(width = .9)) +
  geom_text(aes(group = cty_range,
                y = scale * after_stat(pct(count, x)) - .1,
                label = scales::percent(after_stat(pct(count, x)))),
            stat = "count", position = position_dodge2(width = .9),
            size = 8 /.pt, vjust = 1) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this is pretty awesome, thank you! Would you mind giving a hint to how I could tweak `inset_element()` to fit `p`? For example, if we add `coord_flip()` to `p` we get a [mismatched plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViRov.png). This is the reason why I emphasized in my question the idea of *mapping* the barplots to the `manufacturer` x-axis scale values. I want to be able to generalize the solution as much as possible by using programmatic tools.

Comment: After trial and error, I made some progress and by `p + coord_flip() + inset_element(p_bar + coord_flip(), left = 0.8, bottom = 0, right = 1, top = 1)` it [looks ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PfNf.png). Still. it seems a very error-prone method to me, and I can absolutely see myself screwing up plots this way. Would you have any tips to share on how to minimize the risk of mismatches?

Comment: Hi Emman. I just made an edit to show you an alternative approach without making use of patchwork. But I guess that either approach still requires some additional work to generalize it such that it would work fine for most use cases.